# padding, margin issue with niklasravnsborg laravel-pdf

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I am using a table for the layout of the document. And the CSS is inside the document in a style tag.

I was previously using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf but for Arabic text support, I switched to this package.

My issue is that margin and paddings inside the styles is not getting applied when the pdf is generated. I tried to put the styles inline to each element but the result is the same.

Only font size and bg/color changes but not the margin, padding and height.
Anyone know any solution?